# Loop over objects within objects using terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have a route_table variable containing route table objects which each have several route objects.

```
variable "route_tables" {
  description = "a map of route tables"
  type        = map(any)

  default = {
    "route_table01" = {
      name = "route_table01"
      route = {
        name                   = "route1"
        address_prefix         = "17.65.255.0/24"
        next_hop_type          = "VirtualAppliance"
        next_hop_in_ip_address = "10.18.128.6"
      }
      route = {
        name                   = "route2"
        address_prefix         = "204.61.3.87/32"
        next_hop_type          = "VirtualAppliance"
        next_hop_in_ip_address = "10.18.128.6"
      }
      route = {
        name                   = "route3"
        address_prefix         = "13.61.37.248/29"
        next_hop_type          = "VirtualAppliance"
        next_hop_in_ip_address = "10.18.128.6"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm now trying to loop over them in my module:

```
resource "azurerm_route_table" "route_tables" {
  for_each = var.route_tables

  name                = each.value.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
  tags                = local.tags
  dynamic "route" {
    for_each = each.value.route
    content {
      name                   = each.value.route.name
      address_prefix         = each.value.route.address_prefix
      next_hop_type          = each.value.route.next_hop_type
      next_hop_in_ip_address = each.value.route.next_hop_in_ip_address
    }
  }
}
```

The tf plan completes successfully, but only 1 route is being added to the route table:

[image]

How can I loop over these routes so that all of them are added to the route table?

Comment: You have the same key three times.

Answer (score 1):

I believe one change you'll want to make is that you currently have nothing allowing you to iterate through each nested block. To use for_each, your dynamic block needs to use a different collection as the basis for how it iterates. Instead:

```
resource "azurerm_route_table" "route_tables" {
  for_each = {
    for routes in var.route_tables : routes.name => {
     name                = routes.name
     location            = routes.location
     resource_group_name = routes.resource_group.name
     route               = routes.route
   }
 }    
 name                = each.value.name
 location            = each.value.location
 resource_group_name = each.value.resource_group_name
 dynamic "route" {
    for_each = each.value.route
    content {
      name                   = route.value.name
      address_prefix         = route.value.address_prefix
      next_hop_type          = route.value.next_hop_type
      next_hop_in_ip_address = route.value.next_hop_in_ip_address
    }
  }
}
```

Where your variable might be

```
variable "route_tables" {
  description = "List of route tables to create."
  type        = any
  default     = []
}
```

And your input might be

```
  route_tables = [
    {
      name                = ""
      location            = ""
      resource_group_name = ""
      num_loops   = 2
      route = [
        {
          name                   = ""
          address_prefix         = ""
          next_hop_type          = ""
          next_hop_in_ip_address = ""
        },
        {
          name                   = ""
          address_prefix         = ""
          next_hop_type          = ""
          next_hop_in_ip_address = ""
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Good luck and I hope this helps.

Cheers.